# Why I get this warning? "Member 'x' was not initialized in this constructor"

Tags: c++, c++11, default-constructor

given the following code:

```
class Class {
    int x;
public:
    Class() = default;
};
```

I get the following warning:

> Member 'x' was not initialized in this constructor

What is the reason of this warning?

Comment: That's because your member didn't get initialized

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: Isn't this warning self-explanatory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`x` is an `int` and its default initialization leaves it with an indeterminate value. The simplest, most uniform fix is to value-initialize it in its declaration.

```
class Class {
    int x{}; // added {}, x will be 0
  public:
    Class() = default;
};
```

You could also do `int x = 5;` or `int x{5};` to provide a default value

Answer (score 7):

> What is the reason of this warning?

The `default`ed default constructor does not initialize any members of the fundamental types. Hence, `x` is left uninitialized.

You can fix the problem by using either the member initialization method in the constructor

```
Class() : x(0) {}
```

or in-class member initilaization.

```
int x = 0;
Class() = default;
```